# Secure REST server on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a Python server (basic REST API) running on an AWS EC2 instance. The server supplies the data for a mobile application. I want my mobile app to connect to the python server securely over HTTPS. What is the easiest way that I can do this?

Thus far, I've tried setting up an HTTP/HTTPS load balancer with an Amazon certificate, but it seems that the connection between the ELB and the EC2 instance would still not be totally secure (HTTP in a VPC).

Comment: If you're using HTTPS on your ELB and your instance is in VPC with a [SG that allows inbound traffic from the ELB only](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html#elb-vpc-security-groups) then you don't need to deal with certificates and your instance is not exposed to traffic from the outside world.

Comment: VPC is already secured with Security Group because it prevents access from outside to your servers. Only Internet-Facing ELB is facing to the internet, nobody can attack to your connection between ELB->EC2 instance. VPC is likely as your local network so inside your needwork, do you need to setup secured connection like HTTPS?

Comment: You can terminate SSL on the ELB and leave traffic unencrypted between ELB and EC2, or you can configure ELB to re-encrypt the data between ELB and EC2 (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancer-ssl-support-options/)..

Comment: All of these comments should be in an answer, whether combined as a community wiki or not

Comment: Okay, these comments all seem to indicate that my approach is fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are securing access to an REST API in an EC2 instance, there are several considerations you need to look upon.

- Authentication & Authorization.
- Monitoring of API calls.
- Load balancing & life cycle management.
- Throttling.
- Firewall rules.
- Secure access to the API.
- Usage information by consumers & etc.

Several considerations are mandatory to secure a REST API such as

- Having SSL for communication (Note: Here SSL termination at AWS Load Balancer Level is accepted, since there onwards, the traffic goes within the VPC and also can be hardened using Security Groups.)
- If you plan on getting most of the capabilities around REST APIs stated above, I would recommend to proxy your service in EC2 to [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) which will provide most of the capabilities out of the box.
- In addition you can configure [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) for additional security at Load Balancer(Supports AWS Application Load Balancer).
  You can leverage some of the AWS Services to Handle these.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered in the comments.

It's fine to leave traffic between ELB and EC2 unencrypted as long as they are in the same VPC and the security group for the EC2 instance(s) is properly configured.